# Javascript function keeps on returning null

Tags: javascript, function

So I have been working on a game project where if a player clicks on a letter that if it matches in a phrase to guess, it displays the letter. If the player clicks on a letter without any matches (which is represented by null) then a blue heart turns to a lost heart and the missed counter goes up. For some reason, Even though the player clicks on a matching letter, my code still displays a lost heart. Can anyone help? Here is the github link to the whole project:
https://github.com/santanaquan/Techdegree-Project-6

here is the javascript code snippet.

```html
function checkLetter(button) {
    const getLetter = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    let letter;
    for (let i = 0; i < getLetter.length; i++) {
        if (button.textContent === getLetter[i].textContent) {
            getLetter[i].className += ' show';
            letter = getLetter[i].textContent;
        }
        else {
            letter = null;
        }
    } 
    return letter;
}
```

Comment: If you make a code snippet, it's vastly more helpful if it actually demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: This is a great time to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools to help you narrow down the problem.  For example, if you're convinced that the problem is a single function returning `null` when it shouldn't then you should place a script debugger breakpoint in that function and step through to observe its behavior.  Somewhere you can narrow this down to a specific operation which first produces an unexpected result.  What was that specific operation?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: I bet this `letter = getLetter[i].textContent;` is missing a `break` just after so that it actually ends the loop when a letter is found rather than searching to the end of whatever the loop loops over and then returning `null`.

Comment: As mentioned by @David - try to use browser developer tools. Usually you enable by F12 and helps you to put breakpoints, see current state, evaluate expressions and more :)

Comment: Ive been trying the break; but it makes it so that the letter clicked only matches one time on the phrase even if it contains the letter multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The `checkLetter` function is faulty. I quote the original below for reference:

```
function checkLetter(button) {
    const getLetter =  document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    let letter;
    for (let i = 0; i < getLetter.length; i++) {
        if (button.textContent === getLetter[i].textContent) {
            getLetter[i].className += ' show';
            letter = getLetter[i].textContent;
        }
        else {
            letter = null;
        }
    } 
    return letter;
}
```

The problem here is that `letter` is updated every single time through the loop. This means it ends with whatever value it gets on the last iteration, which will always be `null` unless the last letter was clicked - throwing away any match found on the way.

One very simple fix is to initialise `letter` as `null`, then only change it when a match is found. This guarantees it will have the correct value at the end. So here is a working version:

```
function checkLetter(button) {
    const getLetter =  document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    let letter = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < getLetter.length; i++) {
        if (button.textContent === getLetter[i].textContent) {
            getLetter[i].className += ' show';
            letter = getLetter[i].textContent;
        }
    } 
    return letter;
}
```

Comment: This is correct but breaking the loop on the first match is assuming the same letter can't have multiple occurrences. His loop isn't just checking if the letter exists but also changing CSS for every match.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code iterates over **all** letters, even if the player guesses a correct letter, your code will find it but will then continue to loop after that, this making `letter` null.

You only need to remove the else and initialize `letter` to null. You should **not** break in the if because that way you'll miss duplicated letters.

```
function checkLetter(button) {
    const getLetter = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    let letter = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < getLetter.length; i++) {
        if (button.textContent === getLetter[i].textContent) {
            getLetter[i].className += ' show';
            letter = getLetter[i].textContent;
        }
     }
     return letter;
 }
```

Comment: OK this was the correct fix! With the `break` it makes it so that it only guesses the letter once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others your checkLetter function is broken. You have to stop after you get the match. If you iterate further the letters won't match and the letter variable will be set to null. Modify it to this.

```
function checkLetter(button) {
    const getLetter =  document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    let letter = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < getLetter.length; i++) {
        if (button.textContent === getLetter[i].textContent) {
            getLetter[i].className += ' show';
            letter = getLetter[i].textContent;
            break;
        }
    } 
    return letter;
}
```

Now you have one other problem that is if the letter was already guessed correctly, the loop will not work if there are duplicate characters in the phrase as the first match will set the letter variable. So you will have to add a check in the loop to see if the letter is already matched.

```
function checkLetter(button) {
    const getLetter =  document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    let letter = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < getLetter.length; i++) {
        if (button.textContent === getLetter[i].textContent) {
           if(/*letter is not already guessed*/) {
              getLetter[i].className += ' show';
              letter = getLetter[i].textContent;
          }
        }
    } 
    return letter;
}
```